# Replace string in multidimensionnal array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [objectid] => 197
        [adresse] => D554
        [city] => NEW-YORK
        [lat] => 12,545484654687
        [long] => 12,545484654687
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [objectid] => 198
        [adresse] => D556
        [city] => WASHINGTON
        [lat] => 12,545484654687
        [long] => 12,545484654687
    )
    ...
    ...
)
```

I want to change the city name by an identifier like 0, 1, 2...

Actually, I done this by this code :

```
foreach ($big_array as $key => $value){
    if ($value['city'] == "NEW-YORK"){
        $big_array[$key] = str_replace("NEW-YORK", 0, $value);
    } elseif($value['city'] == "WASHINGTON") {
        $big_array[$key] = str_replace("WASHINGTON", 1, $value);
    } etc...
}
```

I don't think it's the best way to do that, I have a huge list of cities.
Is it possible to define an array like :

```
$replacements = array(
    "NEW-YORK" => 0,
    "WASHINGTON" => 1,
    etc...
)
```

and use a function to perform the change simply ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if ($key['city'] == "NEW-YORK"){`?

Comment: look for `php array_merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the values of the array directly if you pass them by reference

```
foreach ($big_array as &$value) {
    $city = $value['city'];

    // for cities that we don't have a replacement
    if (! isset($replacements[$city])) {
        continue;
    }

    $value['city'] = $replacements[$city];
}

// just to be sure we don't keep any reference to the $value variable
unset($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic with a `$replacements` array, should be something like:

```
foreach ($big_array as $key => $value)
{
    if (!isset($replacements[$value['city']])
    {
        echo "Could not find city '".$value['city']."' in replacements array, skipping";
        continue;
    }

    $value['city'] = $replacements[$value['city']];

    $big_array[$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$find = array(0, 1, etc...);

$replace = array("NEW-YORK", "WASHINGTON", ect ...);

foreach ($big_array as $key => $value){
     $big_array[$key]['city'] = str_replace($find, $value['city']);
}
```